# What's our stance on two questions in the same question?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

While not as recurring as I first imagined, every now and again there will be a question that is actually asking two different questions at the same time. I've picked some of the first examples I could find:

[How can you make someone to respect your wishes?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11726)
[How to handle my girlfriend's parents' attitude to asking her for money?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11682)
[When should I offer my seat on public transport?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/309)
[Under what circumstances is it okay to not hold a door open?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5553)

**Whether the two (or more) questions are explicit or implicit, what is our stance on them?**
There might be cases where both questions are connected, or one follows up on the other, or one follows up based on a specific approach to the other. There might also be cases where one question is IPS-related, while the other is not. It'd be nice to get some perspective on such cases, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

**It depends.**

If the questions are polar opposites, or if they could stand on their own without being supplemented with explanations from the other they should be closed as **too broad**.

For example [How can you make someone to respect your wishes?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/how-can-you-make-someone-to-respect-your-wishes) could stand some better formatting, but really their "questions" are the supplementary of the same core goal.  In this scenario, it'd probably be best to just do an edit and make this one question, such as:

Before:

> How and what to do in order to make others stop making photos or videos about me? How to make others ask my permission before they do this? How do you tell to that person in a way they/ he or she won’t take advantage of it and not make me strange?

After:

> How can I approach my friends/family about only taking pictures of me when they have my permission without provoking them to do it *more* often?

While we may or may not always be able to edit multiple questions down into one question, the key to judging whether more than one question is okay is if the questions are in line with the same goal, or if they are drifting in multiple directions.  It becomes a difference of if the additional questions are just setting extra restrictions/guidelines/filters on answers or if they are *expanding* the scope of potential answers.  Expansions are the problem, not the restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this depends a bit on how related the questions are. If one is a logical follow-up on the other, you might reasonably expect answerers to be able to consider both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Please permit me to observe that there are at least 2 questions in your meta post right here:

> Whether the two (or more) questions are explicit or implicit, what is our stance on them?

and

> There might also be cases where one question is IPS-related, while the other is not. (Implied: What do we do with such Q?)

These are ***obviously related*** and therefore acceptable here, as is the case with most such questions on the main site. If the OP is unknowingly raising too many questions within a post, they are usually advised to focus on the question they consider most important, to avoid closure for being "too broad."

As a special case, when two or more questions are found in a post and only one is really relevant to IPS, all users are encouraged to edit the question (or suggest an edit, depending on their reputation position) to remove the off-topic, non-IPS questions, leaving only the IPS question, so that the post is saved from being closed as both "too broad" and "off topic."

Comment: Funny thing is that, while originally writing the question, I actually *did* have two questions, but tried removing one of them. I placed those cases as examples, because I figured they extended and explained better the main question (for instance, "What is our stance on [questions where one is IPS-related, while the other is not]"), except I generalized the first. But it is a very fair point!

Comment: You are  all right there @HugoBDesigner. I just wanted to point out that it is hard to avoid asking at least 2 related questions, even on meta, so it is not automatically a reason to consider a post on the main site "too broad". But if an OP asks too many sub-questions or maybe 2 unrelated Q, we need them to understand they should focus on one of those and ask the other(s) as another post.